# javascript variable into PHP on modal form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to get a Javascript variable into `PHP` on the same page using a popup modal form. Tried a number of ways. It did not work. Last resort is a cookie which obviously does not work. However, this shows what I am trying to get. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tablex').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');

    $('#example').dataTable({
        "data": dataSet,        
        "columns": xcol
    }); 

    var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function() {    
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');               
            document.getElementById("Delete").style.visibility = "initial";
            nflag = 1;      

            if ($('td', this).eq(0).text() == 'No data available in table') {
                document.popform1.reset();  
                document.getElementById("Delete").style.visibility = "hidden";
            } else {
                vx1 = $('td', this).eq(0).text();
                vx2 = $('td', this).eq(1).text();
                create_cookie('vx1', vx1, 30, "/");
                create_cookie('vx2', vx2, 30, "/");
```

```
<?php
    $cookie_name = 'vx1';
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) 
    {
        print 'Cookie with name "' . $cookie_name . '" does not exist...';
    } else {
        print 'Cookie with name "' . $cookie_name . '" value is: ' . COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }
?>
```

```
                var modal = document.getElementById('frm2x'); 
                modal.click();
            }
        }
    });

    $('#Delete').click(function() {
        table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
    });

    $('#close').click(function() {
        document.popform1.reset();  
        nflag = 1;
        document.getElementById("Delete").style.visibility = "hidden";
    });       
});
```

Comment: why not use a hidden input?

Comment: Please take care when writing your question to format it correctly. This was an unreadable mess before I attempted to fix it for you. Even now you've dumped some PHP code in the middle of your JS. Please edit it to show what your *actual* code is

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass some data from Frontend to Backend ( for you it's PHP), there are 2 approaches for this.

First you can do a FORM and submit it. **This will reload the page.**

Second you need to call an **ajax action to a service** with the data you want to pass. **This won't reload the page.**

To call ajax from javascript:

```
$('#someUniqueButton').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET", // GET or POST
        url: "url/to/action",
        data: {
           x : 15
        }// data you want to pass 
    });
}
```